error in place.placePosition a code where when the user's location shows the list of places
That's the full code
the error happens in place.placePosition, I've already put it without the null check and I put it too, but it gives an error in both
List<PlacesRecord> getPlacesMaximumDistance(
  List<PlacesRecord> places,
  LatLng userGeo,
  double maxDistance,
) {

  List<PlacesRecord> placesList = [];
  List<double> listKm = [];
  double lat1 = userGeo.latitude;
  double lon1 = userGeo.longitude;

  for (PlacesRecord place in places) {
    if(place.placePosition != null){
    double lat2 = place.placePosition!.latitude;
    double lon2 = place.placePosition!.longitude;
   
    var c = math.cos;
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
   
    var d = (12742 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a)));
    String inString = d.toStringAsFixed(2); 
    double inDouble = double.parse(inString);
    listKm.add(inDouble);
   
    listKm.sort();
    int listKmIndex = listKm.indexWhere((dist) => dist == inDouble);
   
    if (inDouble <= maxDistance) {
    
      placesList.insert(listKmIndex, place);
    }
    }
  }
  return placesList;

}

error in
if(place.placePosition != null){
    double lat2 = place.placePosition!.latitude;
    double lon2 = place.placePosition!.longitude;

I've tried everything I know but nothing works
I need this part that is giving error to work but nothing works
If you guys have a better code or explanation, I'll be grateful

what error are you getting?? also are you getting placePosition in response???

@Anand place.placePosition isnt defined in class
